# Generates a random number between 0-100 in a 10x10 matrix and then display numbes greater than 75.

Tags: java, arrays

i am trying to print all numbers greater than 75 but it seems that the only last line of numbers which is greater than 75 will be printed. Any help will be appreciated tnx.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numList = new int[100];
    int column;
    int count = 0;
    for(int row=0;row<10;row++){

            for(column=0;column<10;column++)
            {
            numList[column] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
            System.out.print(numList[column]+"   ");
            }
       System.out.println("   ");
        }
        System.out.println("Greater than 75:");

        for(int row=0;row<1;row++){
            count++;
        for(column=0;column<10;column++)    
        {
            numList[row] = numList[column];
            if(numList[column] >75)
            System.out.print(numList[column]+ ",");

        }
        }


      }         
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You never declare a matrix. You just have a 1-D array which you keep overwriting. For a matrix you need a 2-D array :

```
int[][] numList = new int[10][10];
int column;
int count = 0;
for(int row=0;row<numList.length;row++){
    for(column=0;column<numList[row].length;column++) {
        numList[row][column] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
        System.out.print(numList[row][column]+"   ");
    }
    System.out.println("   ");
}

System.out.println("Greater than 75:");

for(int row=0;row<numList.length;row++) {
    for(column=0;column<numList[row].length;column++) {
        if(numList[row][column] >75)
            System.out.print(numList[row][column]+ ",");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the big help. i see my errors now. Godbless

Answer (score 0):

You are creating 1D array and overriding the first 10 values always in your loop `numList[column] = (int)(Math.random()*100);` , i think 2D array is what you are looking for

```
int[][] numList = new int[10][10];
int column;
for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {

   for (column = 0; column < 10; column++) {
       numList[row][column] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        System.out.print(numList[row][column] + "   ");
    }
   System.out.println("   ");
}
 System.out.println("Greater than 75:");

 for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
    for (column = 0; column < 10; column++) {
         if (numList[row][column] > 75) {
            System.out.print(numList[row][column] + ",");
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. i already solve it now by using 2D array. Godbless :)